# Quicksort not working as expected

Tags: java, quicksort

I'm trying to implement the CLRS pseudo code for quicksort in Java, and I'm not able to get an array to sort correct. The code I wrote is:

```
private void PrintNumbers(int[] numbers) {
    for(int number:numbers) {
        System.out.print(number + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

private void swap(int[] numbers, int i, int j) {
    int temp;
    temp = numbers[j];
    numbers[j] = numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = temp;
}


private int Partition(int[] numbers, int start, int end) {
    int i = start - 1;
    int wall = numbers[end];
    int j;
    for(j = start; j < end - 1; j++) {
        if(numbers[j] <= wall) {
            i++;
            swap(numbers, i, j);
        }
    }

    swap(numbers, i+1, end);
    return i+1;
}

private void QuickSort(int[] numbers, int start, int end) {
    if(start < end) {
        int q = Partition(numbers, start, end);
        QuickSort(numbers, start, q-1);
        QuickSort(numbers, q+1, end);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = {2, 8, 7, 1, 3, 5, 6, 4};
    QS qs = new QS();
    qs.QuickSort(numbers, 0, numbers.length-1);
    qs.PrintNumbers(numbers);
}
```

The output I got for that code is: `2 3 1 4 5 7 8 6`
Any idea what I'm  doing wrong?

Comment: `for(j = start; j < end - 1; j++)` should be `for(j = start; j < end; j++)`. Other thing is in java all the method and variable should start with a lowercase like `PrintNumbers` should be `printNumbers`.

Comment: That seemed to have fixed it. But now I wonder why it was `end-1` in the book though.

Comment: If it is `end-1`, it should be `j<=end-1`. The point here is, the array.length will give you the length of the array and as the index starts from zero we usually do `array.length-1` which will give us the last index. So you are already doing that when you start the `QuickSort` recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for(j = start; j < end - 1; j++)` should be `for(j = start; j < end; j++)`. Other thing is in java all the method and variable should start with a lowercase like PrintNumbers should be printNumbers.

You don't need to subtract one every time as you are doing that while you call the `QuickSort` for the first time from main method.